# React Native blurRadius on local files

Tags: react-native

`blurRadius` seems to be working on images loaded from remote URIs, but not ones that were loaded from my local assets. Any ideas on why this is?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a version issue or any type of styling error because i have tried `blurRadius` on many of my local assets and it worked as expected.
Make sure syntax is correct:

```
<Image 
      source={require('./image.png')} 
      style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
      blurRadius={0.2}
      resizeMode='contain' 
    />
```